# Spring Data Redis on Spring Boot 2.1.0 and Java 11 not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I updated my application to Spring Boot 2.1.0 and Java 11. Since then my Redis is not working anymore.

When I call `findById()` and the result is empty then there are no problems.
When I call `findById()` and there is a result then the application / thread is stuck at this point and nothing happens.

When I use Spring Boot 2.0.6 and Java 9 the same code is working well.

I tried to use `LettuceConnectionFactory` and `JedisConnectionFactory` with the same result.

My Redis Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Bean
    RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());

        return template;
    }
}
```

My entity:

```
@Value
@RedisHash("token")
public class Token {

    @Id 
    private String key;

    private String value;

    @TimeToLive
    private Long expiration;

}
```

My repository just extends the `CrudRepository` and I'm only using provided methods.

Redis-Server version is `Redis server v=4.0.9` running on OSX (dev) / Ubuntu (test).

Did I miss some changes I have to apply to use Java 11 / Boot 2.1 ?

Comment: can you try this `template.afterPropertiesSet()` and `RedisConnectionsFactory.afterPropertiesSet()` then return both objects

Comment: I face the same problem with my mongo after upgrading from spring boot 2.0.3 and java 9 to spring boot 2.1.0 and java 11. Did . Did you find another solution than using @AllArgsConstructor because I don't want to use this library.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of variable key to id.

There is a bug that makes the field with the @Id annotation have to be named id.

```
public class Token implements Serializable {
    @Id private String id;
    private String code;
    @TimeToLive private Long expiration;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I created a test project and saw that the following exception was thrown by the `CrudRepository#findById()` method.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.UncategorizedKeyValueException: No accessor to set property @org.springframework.data.redis.core.TimeToLive(unit=SECONDS)private final java.lang.Long com.test.redisbug.Token.expiration!; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set property @org.springframework.data.redis.core.TimeToLive(unit=SECONDS)private final java.lang.Long com.test.redisbug.Token.expiration!
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValuePersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(KeyValuePersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:55) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.resolveExceptionIfPossible(KeyValueTemplate.java:462) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.execute(KeyValueTemplate.java:348) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.findById(KeyValueTemplate.java:251) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.support.SimpleKeyValueRepository.findById(SimpleKeyValueRepository.java:129) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.findById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.test.redisbug.RedisBugApplication.run(RedisBugApplication.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set property @org.springframework.data.redis.core.TimeToLive(unit=SECONDS)private final java.lang.Long com.test.redisbug.Token.expiration!
    at com.test.redisbug.Token_Accessor_wgdh2l.setProperty(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueAdapter.readBackTimeToLiveIfSet(RedisKeyValueAdapter.java:622) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueAdapter.get(RedisKeyValueAdapter.java:300) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.lambda$findById$3(KeyValueTemplate.java:253) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.execute(KeyValueTemplate.java:346) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

I changed the `@Value` annoation on my entity to `@Data @AllArgsConstructor` and now it's working fine.

Seems like there were some changes in `spring-data-redis`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error and came to the solution by setting `val` to `var` in my kotlin model. I didn't use `@value` or `@Data` or `@AllArgsConstructor`.

```
@RedisHash("keys")
class Token (
        @Id
        val key: String? = null,
        @TimeToLive
        var expiration: Long
)
```

my logs looked like this:

```
org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.UncategorizedKeyValueException: No accessor to set property @org.springframework.data.redis.core.TimeToLive(unit=SECONDS)private final long oauth2demo.oauth2clientdemo.Token.expiration!; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set property @org.springframework.data.redis.core.TimeToLive(unit=SECONDS)private final long oauth2demo.oauth2clientdemo.Token.expiration!
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValuePersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(KeyValuePersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:55) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.resolveExceptionIfPossible(KeyValueTemplate.java:462) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.execute(KeyValueTemplate.java:348) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.findById(KeyValueTemplate.java:251) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.support.SimpleKeyValueRepos
...
```